# Python selenium page source not the same as from website

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to retrieve the page source from a website with Pythons selenium.
But don't receive the expected page source, which I receive with a browser when visiting the website.

Here is a working example of the code. The `chromedriver` file needs to be downloaded first from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import sys

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


def getListings(url):
    chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
    os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

    driver.get(url)

    source_code = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')
    source_code = soup.prettify()

    return source_code



url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Software%20Developer&location=dublin%20ireland&locationId=&trk=jobs_jserp_search_button_execute&searchOrigin=JSERP"

source_code = getListings(url) 
print(source_code)
```

When visiting this website the job listings are shown as JSON, but when getting the page source with `source_code = driver.page_source` the job listings are there with HTML tags. 
I don't understand why the difference?